# Average Values in Excel 2010 Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, average

Good afternoon,

I am sorry if this has been asked before, but I have not been able to find anything that matches what I am trying to achieve.
Effectively I have a large excel table of Project inspection information.
Along the lines of the following:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvNDG.jpg][1]

This example shows data for one project (014031).  What you can see is the total number of actions assigned to that project (27 in this case).
But what I want to get (via pivot tables/charts) is the average number of actions per project - in this case 6.75 (27/4).
Obviously this data contains many projects with all differing numbers of inspections.  Some will only have been inspected once, with 2 actions, some many more with a lot more actions.

Using the standard Average function in the values section gives me a '#DIV/0!' value as I am sure it does not know what to average against.

Is there a way to do this at all?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you mean "average number of actions per project **per day**"?  Is the 4 in "27/4" the number of days that the project was inspected (Oct 7, 11, 25, Dec 2)?

Comment: Hi, no, the number of overall actions (in total) against a project.  In this instance, there are 27 actions and 4 inspections, so therefore an average of 6.75 actions per visit.  Sorry for the confusion.